# Responsive grid with input-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make this responsive (having inputs fluid to fill the whole space):

Keep in mind i need inputgroups and inputs slim right besides!
Input-group-btn width: 0 is a (maybe not perfect) trick to put the inputs right besides each other.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    
 <div class="input-group">
     <label>Strasse</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="strasse" />
  
     
  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
  <label>PLZ</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="plz" style="margin-left:-1px" /></div>
      
      
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      
 <div class="input-group">
    <label>Zimmer</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ><option>ha</option><option>hi</option></select>
  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
    <label>Etage</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ><option>ha</option><option>hi</option></select>
    <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
    <label>Lift</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ><option>ha</option><option>hi</option></select>
</div>      
      
          </div> <!-- end form-group -->
      
      
  </div>
```

You can inspect by minimizing and resizing browser window.

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you should do is wrap input types in col,

play with the snippet-code:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

  
    
 <div class="input-group">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="padding:0;">
     <label>Strasse</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="strasse" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="padding:0;">
     
  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
  <label>PLZ</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="plz" style="margin-left:-1px" /></div>
      
      


<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0;">
   <label>Zimmer</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ><option>ha</option><option>hi</option></select>
  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0;">
    <label>Etage</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ><option>ha</option><option>hi</option></select>
    <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0;">
    <label>Lift</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ><option>ha</option><option>hi</option></select>
</div>   
          </div> <!-- end form-group -->
      
      
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: hardcoded `style="padding:0;"` to override default CSS

Comment: your answer is a regular form ignoring my need to put the inputs next to eachother

Comment: remember that columns always have some padding, to eliminate that you should override default bootstrap behavior;

Comment: if we correct by using margin-left and so on, it behaves different in browsers. but i am open for solid suggestions. anyway thx for the try

Comment: default bootstrap CSS has `padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px` set on every type of column `col-*` ;  this is what's setting the gutter width (for sure!!), you need to edit or override these properties

Comment: if i do this the float is not aligning correct. so i would have to increase the width of each input by the margin-left i take from it. Then there results cross-browser incomptabilities. i try again :)